# Accidental selection of all screen on any click

Tags: gwt, tree

I am working on a GWT application which has a GWT tree freature. When click on any node of the tree, all area on screen got selected without pressing Ctrl+A and all the screen turns blue. I do not want to use below css properties because this is disabling the any selection on the screen.

```
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: none;  
  -ms-user-select: none;   
  user-select: none;
```

How can I avoid this accidental selection?

Comment: Are you updating a DOM structure on click? Sometimes browsers get confused when element just clicked gets removed or changed. If this is your case try to do deferred update.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the follow:

```
new Tree().addHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {             
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }, ClickEvent.getType());
```

The event.stopPropagation() might prevent the "all-selection"-controlhandler from receiving the event at all.

Also, do you have a FocusPanel on the top of your Tree? If you hit that accidently, this might also trigger the behaviour you described